# HTML tags of an article not working

Tags: 8, nodes

I came across this issue. I wrote an article in editor and I put there basic HTML tags like `<strong>` and so on. The thing is, in editor it shows right, but when I publish the article, the HTML tags dont do anything and they are displayed just like normal text.
Do you have any idea why is this happening?
Thank you for any reply

Answer (score 1):

i hope , you have used basic html filter. Basic filter doesn't support all of the tags of html. you have to use full html filter instead of basic html.

Comment: Yes, just found out about it now. Is there any way I can set Full HTML on multiple nodes at once? I have to set it on multiple nodes, so if it is possible to set it on multiple nodes at once so I dont have to edit every node one by one.

Comment: use hook_node_add or hook_node_preserve to achieve this to multiples nodes.

Comment: Alright, can you please tell me where should I put this? I am totally new to Drupal.

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/group/node_api_hooks/7.x

Comment: just put this in your .module file

Comment: `hook_node_add()` and `hook_node_preserve()` are hooks Drupal core invokes.

Comment: The question is for Drupal 8. The list of node hooks invoked from Drupal core 7 isn't much helpful to the OP.

Comment: its also available on drupal 8. just check node api of drupal 8. will get the solution

Comment: In that case, the link should directly take to the Drupal 8 page. With a link for Drupal 7, the OP could think all those hooks are used from Drupal 8 too, which is not the case. Most of those hooks are not for batch processing nodes, so they aren't helping the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the HTML accepted by the filter in use to match your wysiwyg settings, otherwise you are likely to get mismatches like this, where the editor generates HTML that is filtered out before display, or shown as plain text.

Fortunately the field data stored in the database will include the HTML, so you may be able to fix this purely by adjusting the settings of the filter.

Be careful, though, you also need to consider what different classes of users are allowed to do, so if you have a filter that's available to all users you probably want to keep it restricted in terms of the HTML. Configure (and add) filters and editor settings to match user requirements.

Comment: The OP said the HTML tags are showing as plain text. If that is the case, HTML tags aren't filtered out.

Comment: Good catch, in that case the filter must be a plain text one which escapes HTML. Either way, the filter isn't set up right.

Comment: Exactly. I added that in the answer, so the OP cannot think this is not the case described in the question.